# How do you show explained variation in cforest?

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to run a `cforest` model in R with continuous and categorical variables. When I tried this in `randomForest`, the explained variation was ok, but there was a large bias towards continuous variables. Therefore I switched to `cforest`, using the codes provided by Strobl et al.

This was my code:

```
my_cforestcontrol <- cforest_control(teststat="quad", testtype="Univ", mincriterion=0, 
                                     ntree=2000, replace=F)
my_cforest <- cforest(CSBUZZ ~ ., data=all, controls=my_cforestcontrol)
myvarimp <- varimp(my_cforest)
```

However, if I put `print(my_cforest)` or just `my_cforest`, the resulting summary doesn't give the percentage of variance explained. Is there any way I can get that information? I've tried several formula and the R help guide, but I couldn't find it anywhere.